# add faucet to metamask failed

Tags: metamask, testnets, ethereum-classic, faucets

I am using meta mask for the second time and I wanted to add some test ethers in my meta mask from test ether faucet in order to deploy my own smart contract implemented using remix. Unfortunately, eth are not add In my meta mask. I tried to add faucet in different testnet such us Goerli and Sepolia form  several sites and it doesn't work.

Comment: What faucet are you using?
Check if the transaction goes through.
If you are still unable yo get them, let me know you address I can share some sepolia or mumbai tokens.

Comment: I tried all QuickNode Sepolia Faucet,Grabteeth,PoW faucet,Sepolia faucet
FaucETH,Coinbase Wallet Faucet, Sepolia, Alchemy Sepolia faucet,
Infura Sepolia faucet. I need some test ETH in order to deploy a smart contract. My metamask address is 0x0650CCCf61C33bf659B163A72480DcE2128aBbE8.

Comment: Sent 3 sepolia eth. Alchemy faucet works fine for me btw, try to use different browser.

Comment: I have already received 3 sepolia eth, Thank you